# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I create WordPress ShortCode tab and write this code to collect  the shortcode

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#tapSubmit',function(){
    var shortcode = '[tapWrap]';
    jQuery('.tapForm').each(function(){
        var title = jQuery('.Title').val(),
            content = jQuery('.Content').val(),
            shortcode += '[tap ';
        if(title){shortcode += 'title="'+title+'"';}
        shortcode += ']';
        if(content){shortcode += ''+content+'';}
        shortcode += '[/tap]';
    });
    shortcode += '[/tapWrap]';

    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, shortcode);
});
```

and i get this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if
```

and i try the code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and i got this error in the line which have this code

```
shortcode += '[tap ';
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: Remove this `shortcode += '[tap ';` from the var define chain. Otherwise you define it again and there is no value to add to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have

```
var title = jQuery('.Title').val(),
        content = jQuery('.Content').val(),
        shortcode += '[tap ';
```

you are defining new variables in that chain but `shortcode` is already defined, so you are creating a new variable in this scope. Being a new variable you cannot use `+=`. Anyway I think you just want to use this:

```
var title = jQuery('.Title').val(),
    content = jQuery('.Content').val(); // changed the last comma with semicolon
shortcode += '[tap ';
```

**To read:**
About [**scope**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)
About [**var**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 3):

Problem is coming in here

```
var title     = jQuery('.Title').val(),
    content   = jQuery('.Content').val(),
    shortcode += '[tap ';
```

`shortcode` is already a var defined above. You can't use `+=` in a `var` expression

Just change this to

```
var title     = jQuery('.Title').val(),
    content   = jQuery('.Content').val(); // note the semicolon here

shortcode += '[tap ';
```

---

I think you're also going to run into some nesting issue. Instead of calling `jQuery('.Content').val()` for each iteration of the loop, I think you're looking for something more like `$(this).find('.Content').val()` or `$('.Content', this)`. This will find the relevant `.Content` input in the scope of a given `.tapForm`.

I'm thinking something like this, but it's just an idea

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#tapSubmit', function(){

  function title(context) {
    var value = jQuery(".Title", context).val();
    return value ? 'title="' + value + '"' : '';
  }

  function content(context) {
    var value = jQuery(".Content", context).val();
    return value || '';
  }

  var taps = jQuery('.tapForm').map(function(){
    return '[tap ' + title(this) + ']' + content(this) + '[/tap]';
  }).join();

  tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '[tapWrap]' + taps + '[/tapWrap]');  
});
```

Comment: I think you should emphasize that the second `,` has to be replaced with a `;`. That might not be obvious by just looking at the code.